# Single Value Expression in When Then Aggregate Function TSQL

Tags: t-sql, aggregate-functions, etl, common-table-expression, data-mapping

I am trying to map a certain value of a column based on its count on another table. If the count of [Location] i.e a column of IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP table in each row. For now for location static value i.e Utah and Kathmandu is supplied for test purpose only is equal to 1, then only i need to get the result in the select statement i.e only single value expression must be returned but here n rows of table with value is returned.
For. eg. In the below query,total rows of  IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP gets returned, i only need the single first row value in  my case.
I came to know whether cursor or CTE will acheive my result but i am unable to figure it out.
Here,

```
select
case 
when
((SELECT COUNT(stateName) FROM  Location.tblState where stateName = 'Utah')=1)
then (select stateName, CountryName from Location.tblState where stateName= 'Utah')
end as nameof
from IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP
```

The relation between country, state, city is as below:

```
select
case 
when
((SELECT COUNT(cityName) FROM  Location.tblCity where cityName = 'Kathmandu')=1)
then (select ct.countryName from Location.tblCity c
inner join Location.tblState s
on c.stateID = s.StateID
inner join Location.tblCountry ct 
on ct.countryId = s.CountryId
where c.cityName = 'Kathmandu'
)
end as nameof
from IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP
```

How can i return only a single value expresion despite of multiple nmax rows of IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP row in the result.
If i comment out the -- from IMPORT.DATA_SCRAP in the above query i would get the desired single result expression in my case, but unable how can i acheive it in other ways or suggest me the appropriate way to do these types of situation.

Comment: can you post your table schema and data scripts ?